# Can I userdel a user without removing their home directory?

Tags: users, solaris, home, useradd

I did the following:

```
useradd -d /home/iauser -m -s /bin/bash -c "IA User" iauser
```

got this error:

```
UX: useradd: ERROR: Create home directory failed. Operation not applicable
```

It created an entry in passwd:

```
iauser:x:101:10:User:/home/iauser:/bin/bash
```

In Solaris you cannot use `/home` because it is used by the automounter.

## Question:

Can I do this:

```
userdel iauser
```

**without** removing the `/home` directory?

Comment: If you do delete a user and keep that user's home directory, have you thought about what happens when you create a new user that gets the some UID as the user you deleted?  The new user will be listed as the owner of the old, deleted user's home directory and will have access to all the files in that directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't provide the `-r` option to userdel, it should not remove the home directory:

```
SYNOPSIS
     userdel [-r] login
...    
OPTIONS
     The following options are supported:

     -r       Remove the user's home directory from  the  system.
              This  directory  must  exist.  The files and direc-
              tories under the home directory will no  longer  be
              accessible  following  successful  execution of the
              command.
```

Notice that the `-r` option is in square brackets, indicating that it is an optional flag.

[Oracle man pages section 1M: System Administration Commands: userdel](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5166/userdel-1m.html)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the answer might be in your question (or edited in?)

Since /home is usually an automount, you can't create a dir in it.

Comment: It looks like it is in the question because you have answered the context and _not the question itself_.  The question is the part that comes after the word "Question:".